# jQuery/PHP - WYSIWYG Editor To Save $_POST Data

Tags: php, jquery

I found a WYSIWYG editor called Redactor [Redactor Home Page](http://redactorjs.com/). So I'd like to implement this so I can take it and actually save the data. Does anyone have any experience that can tell me how I can get the POST data they say there is? They really do not describe it in any detail for me at least [POST "Tutorial" Here](http://redactorjs.com/docs/settings/) And then go down to UploadFields and there is where they attempt to describe how to get the POST data.

I have a client that would LOVE to have this on his site, any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated,                                                                                 Necro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the setup, this requires you to have a `textarea` in the page. Make sure that element has a name attribute, and when your form is submitted, that'll go to the server.

```
<form method="POST" action="/save_text.php">
    <textarea id="redactor_content" name="content"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#redactor_content').redactor();
    }
);
</script>
```

In save_text.php, your text will be in `$_POST['content']`.